# Real-time monitoring of SQS queue in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, grafana

What's the best way to provide real-time monitoring of the total count of messages sent to an SQS queue?

I currently have a Grafana dashboard set up to monitor an SQS queue, but it seems to refresh about every two minutes. I'm looking to get something set up to update almost in real-time, e.g. refresh every second.

The queue I'm using consumes around 6,000 messages per minute.

Colleagues of mine have built something for real-time monitoring of uploads to an S3 bucket, using a lambda to populate a PostgreSQL DB and using Grafana to query this.

Is this the best way of achieving this? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQS is not event driven - it must be polled.  Therefore, there isn't an event each time a message is put into the queue or removed from it.  With S3 to Lambda there is an event sent in pretty much real time every time an object has been created or removed.

You can change the polling interval for SQS and poll as fast as you'd like.  But be aware that polling does have a cost.  The first 1 million requests a month are free.

Comment: Thanks for this - looks like a lambda is not going to be the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish (I'll address after my idea), but there's certainly a couple ways you could accomplish this. Each has positive and negative.

1. In every place you produce or consume messages, increment or decrement a cloudwatch metric (or datadog, librato, etc). It's still polling-based, but you could get the granularity down (even by using Cloudwatch) to 15-60 seconds. The biggest problem here is that it's error prone (what happens if the SQS message times out and gets reprocessed?).
2. Create a secondary queue. Each message that goes into this queue is either a "add" or "delete" message. Attach a lambda, container, autoscale group to process the queue and update metrics in an RDS or DynamoDB table. Query the table as needed.
3. Use a different queue processing system instead of SQS. I've seen RabbitMQ and Sensu used in very large environments, they will easily handle 6,000 messages per minute.

Keep in mind, there are a lot more metrics than just number of messages in the queue. I've recently become really fond of ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage, because it indicates whether messages are being processed without error. Here's a blog post about the most helpful SQS metrics. It's called [How to Monitor Amazon SQS with CloudWatch](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-monitor-amazon-sqs-with-cloudwatch?utm_source=stack-overflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=social-share)